# How do you script locale installation with CentOS?

Tags: centos, localization

We've been moving servers to EC2 lately and I ran into an issue recently involving locales. We use a script to build an AMI from scratch that is largely based on a simplified RightScale script. However, we recently worked on an international project and I discovered that the locale was not set during the scripted install (issuing *locale* at the command line results in posix). It appear there is no i18n file by default. However, checking a development server that I installed locally (via GUI) the i18n file exists.

What package(s) do I need to install and which program can I run (command line) to configure this during the scripted install?

We're running the current version of CentOS. (5.4)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what provides using the rpm command.  (e.g. rpm -q --whatprovides /full/path/to/your/file )

```
[root@data ~]# rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/ldap.conf

nss_ldap-253-22.el5_4
```

Hope this helps... ;-)

Comment: Worked great, but the result said "not owned by any package." :(

Answer (score 0):

The "-a" flag on locale will show you all locales for which support is installed.  Does that output anything other than posix?

The file /etc/sysconfig/i18n is where the locale gets set for boot time. Here is an example:

```
# cat i18n
LANG="en_GB"
SYSFONT=Lat2-Terminus16
```

That is what you would change in the scripted install (I am assuming that your scripted install is not a "Kickstart" type installation. If it is Kickstart then the "lang" directive controls this).